# C++ Recursive MazeWalker (No Vectors)

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

In the maze, P is path, W is wall, and E is exit. For example here is maze.txt:

```
8 7
5 4
EWWWWWW
PPPPPPW
WWPWWPW
WPPWWPW
WPWWWWW
WPPPPWW
WWWWWWW
WWWWWWW
```

Here is my MazeWalker Class which handles the loading of the file into array (m_maze), recursion, and printing the solution array(m_visited):

```
#include "MazeWalker.h"
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Public Methods
int startX;
int startY;
int sizeRow;
int sizeColumn;

MazeWalker::MazeWalker(string file){
  m_fileName = file;
  fileRead(m_fileName);
  coord1 = startX;
  coord2 = startY;
  m_visited = new int*[sizeRow];
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeRow; i++){
      m_visited[i] = new int[sizeColumn];
    }

  for(int i = 0; i < sizeRow; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < sizeColumn; j++){
      m_visited[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
m_visited[startX][startY] = 1;
}

void MazeWalker::fileRead(string input){
  fstream inFile;
  try{
    inFile.open(input);
    if(inFile.is_open()){
      inFile >> sizeRow >> sizeColumn;
      inFile >> startX >> startY;

      char tempValue;
      m_maze = new char*[sizeRow];
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeRow; i++){
            m_maze[i] = new char[sizeColumn];
        }

      for(int i = 0; i < sizeRow; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < sizeColumn; j++){
          inFile >> tempValue;
          m_maze[i][j] = tempValue;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch(const exception& error){
    std::cerr << error.what() << '\n';
  }

  if(inFile.is_open()){
    inFile >> sizeRow >> sizeColumn;
    inFile >> startX >> startY;

    char tempValue;
    m_maze = new char*[sizeRow];
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeRow; i++){
            m_maze[i] = new char[sizeColumn];
        }

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeRow; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < sizeColumn; j++){
        inFile >> tempValue;
        m_maze[i][j] = tempValue;
      }
    }
  }
}

void MazeWalker::runWalkMaze(){
walkMaze(coord1, coord2);
}

void MazeWalker::printMazeSolution(){
  cout << "Starting Position: (" << startX << ", " << startY << ")\n";
  cout << "Size: " << sizeRow << " x " << sizeColumn << endl;

//display int array
  for(int i = 0; i < sizeRow; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < sizeColumn; j++){
      cout << m_visited[i][j] << "     ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  cout << endl;

  //determine if we escaped the maze
  if(escaped == 'y'){
    cout << "We Escaped!" << endl;
  }
  else{
    cout << "No escape route found!" << endl;
  }
}

//Private Methods
bool MazeWalker::walkMaze(int row, int col){
  if(isExit(row, col)){
    escaped = 'y';
    return(true);
  }

  //Look up
  if(isValidMove(row - 1, col)){
    m_stepCount = m_stepCount++;
    m_visited[row - 1][col] = m_stepCount;
    if(walkMaze(row - 1, col)){
      return(true);
      //row = row++;
    }
  }
  //Look Right
  if(isValidMove(row, col + 1)){
    m_stepCount = m_stepCount++;
    m_visited[row][col + 1] = m_stepCount;

    if(walkMaze(row, col + 1)){
      return(true);
      //col = col++;
    }
  }
  //Look Down
  if(isValidMove(row + 1, col)){
    m_stepCount = m_stepCount++;
    m_visited[row + 1][col] = m_stepCount;

    if(walkMaze(row + 1, col)){
      return(true);
      //row = row--;
    }
  }
  //Look Left
  if(isValidMove(row, col - 1)){
    m_stepCount = m_stepCount++;
    m_visited[row][col -1] = m_stepCount;

    if(walkMaze(row, col - 1)){
      return(true);
      //col = col--;
    }
  }
  return(false);
}

bool MazeWalker::isValidMove(int row, int col){
  if(m_maze[row][col] != 'W'){
    return(true);
  }
  else{
    return(false);
  }
}

bool MazeWalker::isExit(int row, int col){
  if(m_maze[row][col] == 'E'){
    return(true);
  }
  else{
    return(false);
  }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is Mazewalker Header file:

```
#ifndef MAZEWALKER_H
#define MAZEWALKER_H
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MazeWalker{

private:
  char** m_maze = nullptr;
  int m_row;
  int m_col;
  int** m_visited = nullptr;
  int m_stepCount = 1;
  string m_fileName;
  char escaped;
  int coord1;
  int coord2;
  bool walkMaze(int row, int col);
  bool isValidMove(int row, int col);
  bool isExit(int row, int col);

public:
  MazeWalker(string file);
  ~MazeWalker(){}
  void fileRead(string input);
  void runWalkMaze();
  void printMazeSolution();

};
#endif
```

And Lastly main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include "MazeWalker.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

if(argc < 2)
  {
    std::cout << "Incorrect number of parameters!\n";
  }
  else
  {
     MazeWalker myWalker(argv[1]);
     myWalker.runWalkMaze();
     myWalker.printMazeSolution();
  }

  return(0);
}
```

UPDATE: I added the files needed for compiling and at the top the input is "Maze.txt".

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: This could be as simple as `isExit` returning an improper value. [Edit] the question to include a [mre] - preferably, enough code that we can compile it. We need to see the definition of the `MazeWalker` class, the member functions that are used here, and an example `main` that sets up the maze and calls your function.

Comment: *(No Vectors)* -- How would your code be any different in terms of logic if you were to use `vector`?  I bet not much, if any difference.  Also -- [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am just told to use arrays and pointers in my class.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I updated it.

Comment: *I am just told to use arrays and pointers in my class* -- Your teacher is not looking over your shoulder when you are working on this at home.  The trick is to make sure the logic actually works, and that can be quickly done by first using `std::vector` or other container class.  Once you see that it works, then you figure out how to make the home-made 2D array work.  By using `vector`, you could easily determine if you're going out of bounds (using `at()`) and other checks that are not available using dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I suppose that is true, they do see my final code though as I have to turn it in.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm were you able to find anything?